# Flutter - CupertinoActionSheet / CupertinoActionSheetAction background color different on-device than in simulator

Tags: flutter

My Scaffold has a dark background color.

I'm using `showCupertinoModalPopup`, with the `CupertinoActionSheet` and using `CupertinoActionSheetAction` as the children.

In the simulator the actionsheet looks like this:

[image: photo].

When I run the app on my actual iphone, it looks like this:

[image: photo]

The actionsheet items look correct in the sim. Very white in appearance.

On-device though, are way more transparent on-device and therefore are harder to see.

Both `CupertinoActionSheet` and `CupertinoActionSheetAction` do not have color or transparency level properties

Any ideas on what's going on here?

---

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.7, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.29.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

Comment: This is still an issue! Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.3),  Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)

Answer (score 3):

```
return   showCupertinoModalPopup(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoActionSheet(
    actions: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text(
            'Made this my title',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: const Text(
            'next button',
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          child: const Text(
            'next action',
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    ],
    cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
      child: const Text(
        'Cancel',
      ),
      isDefaultAction: true,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Container kills the onPressed effect

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in:

- Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8)
- Mac OS X 10.15.3
- Xcode 11.2.1

I guess it's a bug in Flutter. Or it might be a feature, which I concluded based on [this PR (GitHub link)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/39215).
If You really need to fix it, You will need to modify the code in flutter directly, in the `/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/action_sheet.dart`, inside the `build` method of `CupertinoActionSheetAction`:

```
    return GestureDetector(
      // ...
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        // ...
        child: Semantics(
          button: true,
          child: Container(
            // add decoration property
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: CupertinoDynamicColor.resolve(CupertinoColors.secondarySystemGroupedBackground, context),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_kCornerRadius),
            ),
            // ...
```

Note1: This will work in both light and dark mode on iOS.

Note2: I don't advise You to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone still has problems with the CupertinoActionSheet background color, just wrap the desired CupertinoActionSheetAction widget with a container and assign a color property.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO. Please consider adding a code-snippet to illustrate the ideas that you tried to communicate. That is often easier to understand for new users and quicker to use for experienced users!

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet for anyone that is having issues with cupertino sheet using your theme's primary colors and you want it to look like iOS (blue).

```
    await showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return CupertinoTheme(
            data: CupertinoThemeData(
                textTheme:
                    CupertinoTextThemeData(primaryColor: Color(0xFF3E87F5))),
            child: CupertinoActionSheet(
              actions: [...],
              cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                isDefaultAction: true,
                child: Text('Cancel'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
```